# Parallax Multiple CSS Backgrounds

Tags: css, background, parallax

I've seen a lot of solutions for parallaxing layered divs or sections with background images...I was hoping someone had a solution or knowledge of an existing plugin for parallaxing a div / section with multiple CSS backgrounds, eg:

```
background: url(foo.png), url(foo2.png), url(foo3.png);
background-position: x x, x x, x x;
```

Answer (score 4):

(**Stellar.js)**http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/ ---> This is a javascript library specially for the purpose of parallaxing multiple CSS backgrounds. Example --> http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/backgrounds.html

This might help you with your answer.  cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an answer (nor the reputation to comment on the previous) but know that Stellar.js is unfortunately (still) not capable of exactly what you’re after: https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js/issues/45

Stellar.js requires multiple elements to work.